# Does zero match always "matches" when regex_search returns true?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Here are some quotes from C++11 standard:

> 28.11.3 regex_search [re.alg.search]

`m` is a an argument of `regex_search` of type `match_results`.

> 2 Eﬀects: Determines whether the re is some sub-sequence within [first,last) that matches the regular expression e. The parameter flags is used to control how the expression is matched against the character sequence. Returns true if such a sequence exists, false otherwise.
>
> 3 Postconditions: m.ready() == true in all cases. If the function returns false, then the effect on parameter m is unspeciﬁed except that m.size() returns 0 and m.empty() returns true. Otherwise the effects on parameter m are given in Table 143.

The table 143 states the following about `m[0].matched`:

> true if a match was found, and false otherwise.

The above seems to imply that it is possible for `regex_search` to return `true` and at the same time `m[0].matched` to be `false`. Can someone please provide an example (of regex pattern and text to match) that shows when it is possible?

In other words, with what values of `text` and `re` the following program will not assert:

```
#include <regex>
#include <cassert>
int main()
{
    char re[] = ""; // what kind of regular expression must it be?
    char text[] = ""; // what kind of input text must it be?
    std::cmatch m;
    assert(std::regex_search(text, m, std::regex(re)) == true);
    assert(m[0].matched == false);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the post-conditions information because the C++11 standard (N3337) contains redundant wording in that section.

If `regex_search` returns `false`, meaning a match was not found anywhere within the input string, then the state of the `match_results` object is unspecified, except for the member functions `match_results::ready`, which returns `true`, `match_results::size`, which returns `0`, and `match_results::empty`, which returns `true`.

The result of `match_results::operator[]` is unspecified in that case, and you should not be calling it.

On the other hand, if `regex_search` returns `true`, that means a match was found, in which case `m[0].matched` **will always be `true`**. There is no case where it can be `false` in this situation.

This is clarified in the latest draft N3936, which simply states in Table 143:

> m[0].matched | true

The issue report that brought about this wording change can be [viewed here](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2205). Quoting from it:

> There's an analogous probem in Table 143: the condition for `m[0].matched` is "true if a match was found, false otherwise." But Table 143 gives post-conditions for a successful match, so the condition should be simply "true".

Comment: The results of `match_results::operator[]` on failure/beyond `.size()` are specified in `re.results` (28.10/4) as far as I can tell?

Comment: @Yakk It is, and the info about the zeroth element is consistent there between the C++11 standard and the latest draft. However, reading Table 143 alone, which is the cause of the OP's confusion, does seem to include the possibility that `m[0].matched` may be `false` even when `regex_search` (or `regex_match`) return `true`.

Comment: @Praetorian So I am not misunderstanding anything, its just the mistake in the wording in the standard. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @praetorian but only seems: if (false) `m[0].matched` is `false`, otherwise it is `true` is just a really wordy way of saying `m[0].matched` is `true`.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Table 143 leaks extra information.

If a match was not found, then `m.size()` is zero, and hence `m[0]` returns the unmatched sub expression (as `0` >= `m.size()`), in which case `m[0].matched` is false.

If a match was found, then `m.size()` is non-zero, and hence `m[0]` is the entire matched expression, hence `m[0].matched` is true.  If `m.size()` is greater than 1, then `m[i]` for `i<m.size()` are sub-expressions that are matched by your regular expression.

Had they stated "`m[0].matched`" is always true, then the reference to Table 143 would still be true (as the reference only occurs when there is a match), but it would be overly confusing.

If you examine `re.results` (28.10/4) you'll see that unlike most containers, accessing `[]` beyond `.size()` is valid on a match.